# How Tomcat maps request to a particular application

Tags: tomcat

I recently started using tomcat and I have a query regarding Tomcat request routing/mapping.

Suppose I have deployed four applications A, B, C and D in tomcat server and when some request comes, how tomcat knows which application to invoke or how it routes request to a particular application?

Does it stores information regarding applications in some file?

During an interview, interviewer asked my friend this question. According to interviewer, when request comes to a tomcat server, it checks the details in some file then routes the request to a particular application. Is the file **server.xml**?

Can someone please explain what happens when request comes to tomcat? How it routes the request to a particular application hosted in that server? Where it stores/ preserves these details?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat uses the information in the web.xml files for each webapp, together with any tomcat-specific configuration XML files, to build a map from URLs to servlets.

You should start the reading [the official servlet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).